# Azure Databricks Cluster Questions

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am new to azure and am trying to understand the below things. It would be helpful if anyone can share their knowledge on this.

1. Can the table be created in Cluster A be accessed in Cluster B if Cluster A is down?
2. What is the connection between the cluster and the data in the tables?
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have running process (cluster) to be able to access metastore, and read data, because data is stored in the customer's location, not directly accessible from the control plane that runs UI.

When you wrote data into table, then this data should be available in other cluster in following conditions:

- the both clusters are using the same metastore
- user has correct permissions (could be enforced via Table ACLs)